# How to work with AJAX and Wordpress?

Tags: plugin-development, user-meta

I'm working on my first plugin. I would like to add a follow button for the posts, so the logged in users can follow the authors.

I placed the following lines into functions.php

```
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
       $vars[] = "userID";
       return $vars;
  }
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );

// The code to display the button
function show_follow_button() {
    $author_ID = get_the_author_meta('ID');
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    if ( is_user_logged_in() && $current_user->ID != $author_ID ) {
        return '<a href="#'.$author_ID.'" title="" class="follow-user">Follow</a>';
    }
}

// The update function, I know I have to use array for the ids, it's for only test
$userID = (get_query_var('userID')) ? get_query_var('userID') : false;

if(is_numeric($userID)) {
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    update_user_meta($current_user->ID, 'following', $userID);
}

// jQuery
$('.follow-user').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var userID = $(this).attr('href').slice(1);
    $.ajax({

            type: "GET",
            url: "index.php",
            data: 'userID='+userID,
            success: function(msg){
                $('.follow-user').html('Followed');
            }

        });
});
```

After I click to the follow button I see on the net tab: index.php?userID=X, but nothing happens in the database. Where is the problem?

Comment: I think the problem is with the `if(is_numeric($userID)) {` part.

Comment: An earlier question about AJAX in plugins prompted me to do a write-up with a working example. This might help: http://www.willthewebmechanic.com/ajax-in-wordpress-plugins-a-working-example/

Answer (score 0):

You're not using wordpress default ajax mechanism.

### To do that:

```
jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", // Send request to admin-ajax.php
  data: newcontact, // Can be anything. As per your need
  action: 'myaction', // Required to send otherwise Wordpress AJAX won't authorize your request.
  success: function(data) {
    jQuery(".follow-user").html(data);
  }
});
```

### AJAX Request Handler

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_myaction', 'so_wp_ajax_function' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_myaction' 'so_wp_ajax_function' );
function so_wp_ajax_function(){
  //DO whatever you want with data posted
  //To send back a response you have to echo the result!
  echo $_POST['name'];
  echo $_POST['age'];
  wp_die(); // ajax call must die to avoid trailing 0 in your response
}
```

You can Refer Wordpress Codex. http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins. It's pretty well documented.

Here's already answer question to your problem. i.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17855846/using-ajax-in-a-wordpress-plugin